# Make Indexed File Downloadable In Apache Solr

Tags: apache, solr

I am trying to indexed pdf file to Solr which I have done successfully using the command

```
 curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=id=true"-F myfile=@filename.pdf"
```

I am able to see the file contents and search, but when I try to click on file name it shows

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/collection1/id. Reason: 
not found
```

What I want is to have a link which allows downloading the file, I know Solr merely indexes the file and stores it. I was wondering if there is a way by which I can add attribute location like you have done and proceed from there, can you please share with me what you have done, if you want any more clarity regarding my problem do ask.

Answer (score 0):

We have the actual files hosted through a separate web application to be download from with auditing and additional security.
you can always directly host these files through http server.
If you are having the file names with id, it is as easy as appending the id.extension to the fixed http hosted url.
Else index the path of the file with an additional parameter e.g. literal.url. 
The url will the solr field which will now be available with the Solr response.

Comment: There's this great answer on storing to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16892935/604511

Comment: it still doesn't store the files in Solr which you cant do and have to render from outside solr.

Comment: My bad, should have typed "storing to FS"