# Store Images to display in SOLR search results

Tags: image, apache, solr, indexing, jackrabbit

I have built a SOLR Index which has the image thumbnail urls that I want to render an image along with the search results. The problem is that those images can run into millions and I think storing the images in index as binary data would make the index humongous.

I am seeking guidance on how to efficiently store those images after rendering them from the URLs , should I use the plain file system and have them rendered by tomcat  , or should I use a JCR repository like Apache Jackrabbit ?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: metadata in Solr if you require searching on it. Store the images themselves on 1. S3 (+ cloudfront) or 2. Mongo Gridfs.

Answer (score 1):

I would evaluate the effective requiriments before finally deciding how to persist the images.

Do you require versioning?
Are you planning to stir eonly the images or additional metadata?
Do you have any requirements in horizontal scaling?
Do you require any image processing or scaling?
Do you need access to the image metatdata?
Do you require additional tooling for managing the images?
Are you willing to invest time in learning an additional technology?

Storing on the file system and making them available by an image sppoler implementation is the most simple way to persist your images. 
But if you identify some of the above mentioned requirements (which are typical for a content repo or a dam system), then would end up reinventing the wheel with the filesystem approach.

The other option is using a kind of content repository. A JCR repo like for example Jackrabbit or it's commercial implementation CRX is one option. Alfresco (supports CMIS) would be the another valid.
Features like versioning, post processing (scaling ...), metadata extraction and management belong are supported by both mentioned repository solutions. But this requires you to learn a new technology which can be time consuming. Both mentioned repository technologies can get complex.
If horizontal scaling is a requirement I would consider a commercially supported repository implementations (CRX or Alfresco Enterprise) because the communty releases are lacking this functionality.

Me personally I would really depend any decision on the above mentioned requirements. 
I extensively worked with Jackrabbit, CRX and Alfresco CE and EE and personally I would go for the Alfresco as I experienced it to scale better with larger amounts of data.

Comment: Thomas, thank for a great reply , as of now I do not require any of the features , like versioning , mata data extraction etc , scaling is a definitely a concern , as the data grows I would think I would need to scale it horizintally. Are there any pointers to a simple pooling mechanism using Tomcat. Just to make sure if I was not clear enough in my earlier comment , I want to store images from the thumbnails of those images and those images would only be valid for a given crawl window, meaning I am using a crawler and the images need to be deleted/updated during the next crawl session. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a image pooling solution that fits your needs exactly but it shouldn't be to difficult to implement that, apart from the fact that recurring scaling operations may be very resource intensive.

I would go for the following approach if FS is enough for you:

- Separate images and thumbnail into two locations.
- The images root folder will remain, the thumbnails folder is
  temporary.
- Create a temporary thumbnail folder for each indexing run.
- All thumbnails for that run are stored under that location, scaling
  can be achived with i.e ImageMagick.
- The temporary thumbnail folder can then easily be dropped as soon as
  the next run has been completed.

If you are planning to store millions of images then avoid putting all files in the same directory. Browsing flat hierarchies with two many entries will be a nightmare.
Better create a tree structure by i.e. inverting the current datetime (year/month/day/hour/minute ... 2013/06/01/08/45).

This makes sure that the number of files inside the last folder get's not too big (Alfresco is using the same pattern for storing binary objects on the FS and it has proofen to work nicely).

Comment: Thanks again for a detailed reply , I only need to maintain the thumbnails,the ImageMagick pointer is really helpful to scale down images.I will look into Alfresco to serve as a repository , but I was hoping for a more easier solution like using Tomcat by itself , however I think scaling would be an issue, if I have to learn a new technology i.e Alfresco so be it . Thank You.